# Prove this identity using inequalities

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For some diagonal matrix **A** = $(a_{ij})$ where the main diagonal are all positive numbers ($a_{ii} > 0$ for $1\le i \le n$), prove:

$$
\textbf{v}^T \textbf{A} \textbf{w} \le \|\textbf{A}^{1/2}\textbf{v}\|_2 \|\textbf{A}^{1/2}\textbf{w}\|_2
$$

We also define the matrix square root of **A** as $\textbf{A}^{1/2} = (a_{ij}^{1/2})$.

I tried playing around with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove this, but I think I'm just confusing myself even more. Any solution or suggestions?

Comment: That's not quite the definition of the matrix square root. Defined correctly it should follow immediately from Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: @CalvinKhor For a diagonal matrix with nonnegative eigenvalues... it coincides.

Comment: @ClementC. ah, I missed the word diagonal at the start. My apologies to OP

Answer (score 1):

What is confusing is that the definition of the square root seems odd at first; but all simplifies once you remember that $A$ is assumed to be *diagonal*:
$$
\mathbf{v}^\top A \mathbf{w} = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}\mathbf{v}_i \mathbf{w}_j
\stackrel{(1)}{=} \sum_{i} a_{ii}\mathbf{v}_i \mathbf{w}_i
\stackrel{(2)}{=}\sum_{i} \sqrt{a_{ii}}\mathbf{v}_i \cdot \sqrt{a_{ii}} \mathbf{w}_i
\stackrel{(3)}{\leq}\sqrt{\sum_{i} a_{ii}\mathbf{v}^2_i } \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{i} a_{ii}\mathbf{w}^2_i }
$$
where (1) uses the fact that $A$ is diagonal, (2) the fact that the entries are nonnegative, and (3) is Cauchy-Schwarz.

Now, you can easily check that
$
\| A^{1/2} \mathbf{v}\|_2^2 = \sum_{i} a_{ii}\mathbf{v}^2_i
$
and similarly for $
\| A^{1/2} \mathbf{w}\|_2^2$, so the RHS above is exactly
$\| A^{1/2} \mathbf{v}\|_2\cdot \| A^{1/2} \mathbf{w}\|_2$.